# Trying to get two UICollection Views in one view controller. only one showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to have two UICollectionViews for an app I'm working on. I'm able to get one, which is populated by Firebase to show up (imageCollection). Unfortunately, I'm unable to get the second one to show up (popImageCollection). All my outlets are there. I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Here is my View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var popImageCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView!

    var customImageFlowLayout = CustomImageFlowLayout()
    var images = [BlogInsta]()
    var popImageArray = [UIImage]()

    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    var dbPopularRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("images")
        dbPopularRef = Database.database().reference().child("popular")
        loadDB()
        loadImages()
        customImageFlowLayout = CustomImageFlowLayout()
        imageCollection.backgroundColor = .white

        popImageCollection.delegate = self as? UICollectionViewDelegate
        popImageCollection.dataSource = self

        imageCollection.delegate = self as? UICollectionViewDelegate
        imageCollection.dataSource = self

        self.view.addSubview(popImageCollection)
        self.view.addSubview(imageCollection)
    }

    func loadImages() {
        popImageArray.append(UIImage(named: "1")!)
        self.popImageCollection.reloadData()
    }

    func loadDB() {
        dbRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImages = [BlogInsta]()
            for BlogInstaSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                let blogInstaObject = BlogInsta(snapshot: BlogInstaSnapshot as! DataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(blogInstaObject)
            }

            self.images = newImages
            self.imageCollection.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.imageCollection {
            let cell = imageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
            let image = images[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image.url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1"))
            return cell
        } else {
            let cellB = popImageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "popCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularCollectionViewCell
            let popPhotos = popImageArray[indexPath.row]
            cellB.popularImageView.image = popPhotos
            return cellB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried UI debug? I don't see the frame settings in your code so I believe your popImageCollection is behind your imageCollection.
Also if you are using IBOutlets, why are you adding the collectionView as subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If collections are in IB don't add them again

```
self.view.addSubview(popImageCollection) // remove
self.view.addSubview(imageCollection) // remove
```

Also

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     if collectionView == self.imageCollection {
          return images.count 
      }  
      else { 
         return popImageArray.count 
      }
}
```

//

Delegate should be in class declaration as not to be set to nil at runtime

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Comment: Life saver! Thank you!